# header tab is not padding properly...... and i want to hide the white color with gray color

Tags: html, css

This is header.php code:

```
<div class="header" style="background-image:url(images/tm-playing-cards-manufacturer.jpg);background-size: 100% 100%;">
  <div class="container" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization">
    <!--Logo of Company-->
    <div class="head-mid" style="color:#fff;">&nbsp;
    </div>
    <div class="logo">
      <h1 style="padding-top:20px;">
        <a itemprop="url" href="/" style="color:#00a79d;padding-top:15px;" >
          <img itemprop="logo" class="img-responsive" src="http://www.tmcards.com/images/tm-cards-manufacturer.png" alt="TMcards playing card manufacturer company" width="100%" height="100%"/>
        </a>
      </h1>
      <p align="center" style="padding-top:20px;">
        <a href="playingcards-advance.php">
          <img itemprop="image" src="http://www.tmcards.com/images/tmcards-quote-form.png" width="140" height="35" alt="deck of playing cards" border="0"/>
        </a>
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="head-mid" style="float:right;">&nbsp;
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


This is style.css 
 <style>

    body {

       font-size:12px;
    }

                .header_nav 
                {
                    background-color: #ccc;
                }
                li.las a 
                {
                    border-right: none!important
                }
                .icn_pos 
                {
                    font-size: 16px;
                    padding-left: 20px;
                }
                .icn_pos.hm 
                {
                    padding-left: 12px;
                }
                .icn_pos.hm2 
                {
                    padding-left: 40px;
                }
                .navbar-default .navbar-nav>li 
                {
                    padding: 0;
                    text-align: center;
                    float:left;
                    list-style-type:none
                }
                .navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:focus,
                .navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a 
                {
                    padding: 16px 38px;
                    text-decoration:none;
                    color: #000!important;
                    font-weight: 1000;
                    font-size: 18px;
                    float:left;
                    background: #ccc;
                    border-right: 1px dotted #fff;

                }
                .navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a {
                    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif


                }
                .carousel-indicators .active {
                    background-color: #020202!important
                }
                .image-wid img {
                    width: 100%
                }
                .navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:focus,
                .navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:hover {
                    background: #00a79d!important;
                    border-radius: 2px;
                    transition: .6s all

                }
                .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a,
                .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover,
                .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus {
                    background: #00a79d!important
                    text-decoration:none;
                }
                .glyphicon {
                    color: black;
                    font-size: 1em;
                    margin-right: 5px
                }

                .navbar-right {
                    float: none!important;
                    margin-right: 0;
                    float:left;
                }
                .navbar-default {

                    border: none
                }

                .navbar {
                    position: relative;
                    min-height: 103px;
                }

                .navbar-collapse {
                    padding-right: 0;
                    padding-left: 0
                }
                .headertabs {
                    background: #231D2B
                }

                #headerdiv {
                    color: #fff;
                    font-size: 14px
                }

                .headertabs #headerdiv h1 {
                    color: #fff;
                    font-size: 18px;
                    font-weight: 700;
                    text-decoration: none;
                    padding: 3px 0 7px
                }
                .headertabs #headerdiv h2 {
                    color: #ccc;
                    font-size: 15px;
                    font-weight: 700;
                    text-decoration: none
                }
                .headertabs {
                    background: #231D2B
                }
                #headerdiv {
                    color: #fff;
                    font-size: 14px
                }
                .headertabs #headerdiv h1 {
                    color: #fff;
                    font-size: 18px;
                    font-weight: 700;
                    text-decoration: none;
                    padding: 3px 0 7px
                }
                .headertabs #headerdiv h2 {
                    color: #ccc;
                    font-size: 15px;
                    font-weight: 700;
                    text-decoration: none
                }
```

[This is header page error and i m getting white in some part of navigation and i want to make it gray color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dCUzw.png)

The page is showing not proper navigation padding is missing or any style property. My navigation bar should be filled with gray color but some part of navigation is white color. On the white part i want to add padding property nad aother property so that white color is removed and in place of white gray color is there actually i want to give padding style property not color property. The page is showing not proper navigation padding is missing or any style property.

My navigation bar should be filled with gray color but some part of navigation is white color. On the white part i want to add padding property nad aother property so that white color is removed and in place of white gray color is there actually i want to give padding style property not color property.

Comment: If you are working live! please provide working url or make us for jsfiddle!

Answer (score 0):

use this one it's helpfull

```
body {

   font-size:12px; margin:0px; padding:0px;
}
```